# Script to get Key Vault secret values from API management policy at run-time and pass them to backEnd URL

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-keyvault

Can I get a script to get Key Vault secret values from API Management Policy at run time & pass them to backend URL? I tried to search in number of blogs but doesn't get any help yet.

Comment: When you say you'd like to "get" a script, have you tried writing one? If so, what problem did you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<send-request/>` policy to call the keyvault rest endpoint. In the response variable in the policy, helps to parse through the response. In this way , you can call it dynamically.

Refer the example in the below link to know about the `<send-request/>` policy 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#SendRequest

Comment: Thank you VinuBibin. The send-request policy worked for me